# Is there a way to estimate building movements?

Tags: sensors

I wish to determine if, or how much, movement there is of the building in which I'm currently living. Is there any way for me to do this? Is it even possible at all based on phone hardware?

Comment: App shopping suggestions are generally off-topic, as per the FAQ.

Comment: Ooops... You are right. Should I delete this question or mark it in special way? Also, where Can I ask some application search related questions?

Comment: @Damian Are you really want to track the "movement" of a building (geological) or do you want information about in-house navigation?

Comment: @Flow "Movement" - if the building is moving when there is wind blowing from one direction.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot track your building's movements with the GPS. Its accuracy isn't better than ~10m. If your house does move that much, you won't need any hardware to detect it.

Comment: I was thinking about phone accelerometers. Maybe they are sensitive enough?

Comment: @Damian Go and find out. Install an sensors App and place your phone on a table and see if the sensors catch anything.